# Does an RTX3080/TI fit in a Carbide Series 400R Mid-Tower

Tags: graphics-card, case, case-layout

I have a Carbide Series 400R Mid-Tower Gaming Chassis which I bought 7 years ago.  It has held a RX580 and now has a GTX1660 Super in it.  I am looking to upgrade to a RTX3080 variant and they appears to be 320mm long.

https://www.scan.co.uk/products/gigabyte-nvidia-geforce-rtx-3080-vision-oc-rev20-10gb-gddr6x-ray-tracing-graphics-card-8704-core-180

My case states that the maximum GPU is 318mm.

https://www.corsair.com/uk/en/Categories/Products/Cases/Carbide-Series%E2%84%A2-400R-Mid-Tower-Case/p/CC-9011011-WW#tab-tech-specs

Is this 2mm really the difference between fitting and needing a brand new case?  It isn't a small case by any means, but not sure what tolerances there are for air flow etc.  2mm is an annoyingly tiny amount where you think the card manufacturers are doing it just to annoy you.

Comment: “Is this 2mm really the difference between fitting and needing a brand new case?” - It’s probably the difference between the case having a side installed and it not being installed.  2 mm is more than you think when dealing with industrial tolerances.  The solution get a different 3080 card that’s slightly smaller

Comment: I would also be a little concerned about there not being sufficient airflow if there are no gaps between the components and the case. Further, if your GPU is right up against the case, you may struggle to plug power cables in to the card as well